# How to count the number of products between two same length ranges is 0 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two ranges of columns that I would like to count the number of times the product between two cells at corresponding indexes is 0. Right now I am currently counting via brute force via the below example.

=IF(OR(A3=0,F3=0),1,0)+IF(OR(B3=0,G3=0),1,0)+IF(OR(C3=0,H3=0),1,0)+IF(OR(D3=0,I3=0),1,0)+IF(OR(E3=0,J3=0),1,0)

Is there a way to accomplish the same but without having to write out all of the IF statements and simply pass the arrays?

Below is an example where columns with same name will be multiplied and in the final "Outcome" column i want to get the count where that product is 0.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your data?  Makes it much easier to help.

Comment: Let me know if the updated formula and added table assist your understanding in what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: countif https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: COUNTIF and COUNTIFS are not sufficient because they do not compare the product of two different ranges as illustrated in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your logic, I think this will do it:

```
=SUM(N(((A2:E2=0)+(F2:J2=0))>0))
```

Comment: This is giving me a #VALUE! error unfortunately when using either * or +.

Comment: @magic_frank: If you don't have 365, you need to use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to confirm it as an array formula.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You need to use "+" and not "*" to accomplish what I am looking for. Thanks for reminding me i need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @magic_frank: If you use `+`, it will count the number of cell pairs where at least one cell is 0 (your requirement). If you use `*`, (it seems like) it will count the number of cell pairs where both cells are 0.

Comment: @VBasic2008 `+`=`or` and `*` =`and`.  I used `+`  since his formula used a bunch of `or`'s.